# error: package org.jsoup.Jsoup does not exist while compiling the class using command prompt

Tags: java, jsoup, command-prompt

While compiling a java class in which I had imported packages such as `org.jsoup.Jsoup`, the following error was retrieved:

> package org.jsoup does not exist.

I don't know how to add the classpath for `jsoup-1.8.1.jar` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
java -cp .:jsoup-1.8.1.jar JsoupTest
```

Comment: @aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa. I get same error on Android Studio 2.2 ! How fix it on Android Studio 2.2 ?

Comment: but then i get Error: Could not find or load main class JsoupTest

Comment: @YehudaClinton did you find a way to run main class using jsoup?

Comment: @KirtiParghi its been a while. i dont i ever figured it out and used something else